# How can I mathematically represent a graph like this?s

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions

[image]

I apologize for the HORRIBLE graphic, but what is the equation of a line like the one above? The gradient increases the closer x gets to 1

Answer (score 3):

It could be something like

$$f(x)=\frac x{1-x}\;,\;\;0\le x<1$$

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/f40ae447e0bc4ed77a0d173273f4a822.png Awesome man, thanks

Comment: How can I decrease the gradient gain so that f(x) doesn't increase as much until x is closer to 1?

Comment: @BasicallyAlanTuring You could both take $\;x^{1/n}\;$ for some high value of $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ and also multiply the whole thing by a positive high number. Anyway, after you're "close enough" to one, the graph is going to be pretty steep.

Comment: A lazy way would be to make the numerator $x^n$, where larger n will make the curve shallower closer to zero. @DonAntonio, using $x^{1/n}$ will qualitatively change the shape of the graph by creating an inflection point

Comment: @Samadin The OP seems to be concerned only about how steep the graph is close to one, so inflexion points and stuff don't seem to be, at least from what I can understand, an issue here. Your advice to use $\;x^n\;$ makes things worse as the function will be steeper in this case close to $\;1\;$ ...

Comment: @Don, oh, I thought that's what the OP wanted, shallow closer to 0 and steeper close to 1. Your suggestion certainly works.

Answer (score 3):

Another function:
$$f(x)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\;,\;\;0\le x<1$$
whose graph can be seen [HERE](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20tan(pi%2F2*x)%20in%20%5B0,1)) .